# chrono: How can I calculate a millsecond duration from two high resolution time points?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am trying to calculate a chrono `duration` from two chrono `time_points` like so

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
    time_point<high_resolution_clock> start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    time_point<high_resolution_clock> end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration<milli> difference = duration_cast<milli>(end - start);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/wUKb9S

I am totally puzzled by the compiler error messages:

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0

prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:63: error: no matching function for call to 'duration_cast(std::__success_type<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >::type)'
  duration<milli> difference = duration_cast<milli>(end - start);
                                                               ^
prog.cpp:9:63: note: candidate is:
In file included from prog.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/chrono:194:7: note: template<class _ToDur, class _Rep, class _Period> constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::chrono::__is_duration<_Tp>::value, _ToDur>::type std::chrono::duration_cast(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&)
       duration_cast(const duration<_Rep, _Period>& __d)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/chrono:194:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/chrono: In substitution of 'template<class _ToDur, class _Rep, class _Period> constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::chrono::__is_duration<_Tp>::value, _ToDur>::type std::chrono::duration_cast(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&) [with _ToDur = std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll>; _Rep = <missing>; _Period = <missing>]':
prog.cpp:9:63:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/chrono:194:7: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >'
```

Is the difference between two `time_point`s not a duration? Can I not convert between duration types to get a millisecond duration representation?

Answer (score 4):

`milli` is an typedef for `std::ratio<1, 1000>` which is not a valid representation for a `duration`, it should be something like `duration<long, milli>`, or simply `std::chrono::milliseconds`

```
auto difference = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
```

Comment: Note if you're using Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 (with Windows), the "high resolution clock" is just the standard ticker that runs at 64hz. You can use [timeBeginPeriod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the  ticker to 1ms (1000hz on Vista and later, 1024hz on XP with 3 extra delays every 125 ms to average 1000hz).

Comment: @theoB610, the type that you cast to, i.e. `milliseconds`. Why not try reading some docs? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast

Comment: @theoB610, try searching the web or asking your own questions instead of adding off-topic comments. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148289/should-i-use-the-new-c11-auto-feature-especially-in-loops